# Why doesn't my program print?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and I got stuck.

I want to write a code which collects the multiples of 3 and 5 in range of 1000 in a list and sum it up. Now I capable to do that in the shell by writing:

```
numbers = []

for number in range(1001):
  if number%3 == 0 or number%5 == 0:
    numbers.append(number)

sum (numbers)
```

and it gives me the answer 234168 so this works, however, if I write this in to file:

```
def multiples():
 numbers =[]
 for number in range(10):
  if number%3 == 0 or number%5 == 0:
      numbers.append(number)
  sum (numbers)


multiples()
```

then in the shell python will inform me that the code ran, but doesn't give me back anything! I tried using print, removing spaces, relocating the lines but it just doesn't give me back the result.(not even an error message)

Please help me because this drives me crazy and I would like to apologize for any writing mistakes since English is not my native language.

Comment: Try `return sum(numbers)`

Comment: I don't see print() being called anywhere.

Comment: _"I tried using print"_ OK, that's a step in the right direction. Please show us the code where you tried using print.

Comment: Well, I tried using it in the wrong way, like this:
print (sum (numbers)) or print (numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiples():
  numbers = []
  for number in range(10):
    if number % 3 == 0 or number % 5 == 0:
      numbers.append(number)

  return sum(numbers)

print (multiples())
```

output:

```
23
```

Comment: you should also return sum (numbers) from function else, You are would be printing None to console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helped, thank you again, and I hopefully learn forever now to use the return properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the sum of the numbers in your `multiples` function.
Try it with a function looking like this:

```python
def multiples():
  numbers =[]
  for number in range(10):
    if number%3 == 0 or number%5 == 0:
      numbers.append(number)
  return sum(numbers)
```

When you ran your code step by step in the python shell, the shell always prints the result of the last statement, so it printed what the `sum(numbers)` statement calculated. When using a function, you need the return statement ([Python Docs: Return Statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement)) in order to pass values to the calling scope of the function.